# Is there a good free Flat style map tile available?

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I'm building a website in the style of [Flat Design](http://www.awwwards.com/flat-design-an-in-depth-look.html), and hoping to find a map tile that complements the design and can be used with Leafletjs.

Comment: Does Stamen's Toner map qualify?

Comment: That looks really nice, but I wonder how difficult it would be to change the coloring.

Comment: By the time you've built your website, I reckon flat design won't be trendy any more... It's so 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If style and design is what you want then [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) is a good option. They have a free plan as long as you don't go over the max. https://www.mapbox.com/plans/. You can use either mapbox.js (which is based apon leaflet) or tink to the tiles that you have predefined in mapbox. You can go really far in the design of a map.

If you really want free and unlimited you should check out openstreetmaps. I use it all the time and it suits my needs (interactive visualisations on blog) perfectly. [Example](http://wishfishes.apps.runkite.com/biased-maps/).

To call openstreetmaps in Leaflet; 

`L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")`

[Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/) also offers free tiles but only to a certain amount of views and doesn't offer as much flexibility as mapbox does. An alternative, if you are willing to part with Leaflet, is to use [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/). CartoDB allows you to place a map via an iframe. I am naming it because CartoDB does offer flexibility in the color and the design which might suit your flat design needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[Google Maps custom style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)** to design your tiles in a flat style and integrate this custom tiles with leaflet using the [leaflet-plugins](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins) plugin - *if the usage of Google tiles within leaflet is an option* for you, as the Google Maps API Terms of Service apply. The plugin [supports custom styles](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/pull/86) via its *mapOptions* object since version 1.0.1.

Custom Google Map styles can be visually generated via the [Google Maps API Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), which outputs a MapOptions JSON object, and it is possible to specify the look (visibility, colour etc) of several kinds of features on the map. You can generate a *flat-design map style* if you take the *roadmap* base tiles and turn off visibility of certain layers, most probably the landscape terrain, and define a custom, simple colour scheme to various other features, e.g. the water. There are some limitations though, you cannot customize everything (for example, the terrain basemap will always show terrain).

I recommend to have a look at the styles wizard in order to check if the available customization options fit your needs.

For leaflet integration, the plugin website provides a [sample code](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/google-custom.html) that illustrates the implementation of such custom styles in leaflet. In short:

```
var styles = [                                        // this is the JSON object
   {  "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",     // which is passed to google
      "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ]          // in order to customize the style
   }                                                  // of your tiles
]                                                     // 

var ggl = new L.Google('ROADMAP', {
              mapOptions: { styles: styles }        // apply the custom style to your map
          });
map.addLayer(ggl);
```